# Is there any way to make an Point (datatype) to be an array?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Dim polygon() as new Point.

I want to make this an two dimensional array. So I can call the specific polygon with its following points.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to store two points for each polygon?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a loop:

```
Dim p2(UBound(polygon), 1) as Integer

For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(polygon)
  p2(i, 0) = polygon(i).x : p2(i, 1) = polygon(i).y
Next i
```

You might want to make sure you really need the points in a 2-dimensional array. It might not be necessary.